# Cannot use my MySQL Database with Django - ValueError after running migrate command

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm working with Django 3.0 and after playing a bit with this framework, I would like to connect it to my big MySQL Database.
My goal is to be able t**o set up the Admin Django Dashboard with my all my data from my MySQL Database**.

So far, after seeing some tutorials, this is what I've done :

**Settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': "django.db.backends.mysql",
    'NAME': "nameDB",
    'USER': "root",
    'PASSWORD': "mypassword",
    'HOST': "myHost",
    'PORT': "",
    'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
    }
  }
}
```

My App (let's say dashboard) is installed on my INSTALLED_APPS.

Then, I did :

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

It generate well the models.py. So I moved the models.py to my Dashboard app folder. After that, I wanted to migrate my DB using this following command line :

```
python manage.py migrate
```

At this step, there are some errors that I'm not able to solve.

**Errors**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nameUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\nameUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\nameUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\nameUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
(base) PS C:\xampp\htdocs\django-test\app> python .\manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nameUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\nameUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute        
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\nameUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\nameUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\nameUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\nameUser\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I did

```
Python manage.py check
```

And I got the same errors. I cannot do anything until I removed my dashboard app.

I precise that I did the same thing with a new empty MySQL Database and it worked well. I was able to create a super user for Admin and go into the Admin Dashboad.

So, I think there is a problem with my current MySQL Database but I don't know what.

Could you please help me on that please ?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of struggling, I was able to find the issue.

When you run the command

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

The file is encoded to UCS-2 which is not utf-8 format. So I changed the encoding to utf-8 and I don't have this error anymore.
The question is : how to force the inspectdb command to encode in utf-8 ?

But well, my problem is solved so far.